# 'grep +A': print everything after a match

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a file that contains a list of URLs. It looks like below:

file1:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.bing.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.baidu.com
http://www.yandex.com
....
```

I want to get all the records after: http://www.yahoo.com, results looks like below:

file2:

```
http://www.baidu.com
http://www.yandex.com
....
```

I know that I could use grep to find the line number of where yahoo.com lies using

```
grep -n 'http://www.yahoo.com' file1

3 http://www.yahoo.com
```

But I don't know how to get the file after line number 3. Also, I know there is a flag in grep -A print the lines after your match. However, you need to specify how many lines you want after the match.  I am wondering is there something to get around that issue. Like:

```
Pseudocode:

grep -n 'http://www.yahoo.com' -A all file1 > file2
```

I know we could use the line number I got and `wc -l` to get the number of lines after yahoo.com, however... it feels pretty lame.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

#### AWK

If you don't mind using [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '/yahoo/{y=1;next}y' data.txt
```

This script has two parts:

```
/yahoo/ { y = 1; next }
y
```

The first part states that if we encounter a line with *yahoo*, we set the variable y=1, and then skip that line (the `next` command will jump to the next line, thus skip any further processing on the current line). Without the `next` command, the line *yahoo* will be printed.

The second part is a short hand for:

```
y != 0 { print }
```

Which means, for each line, if variable y is non-zero, we print that line. In AWK, if you refer to a variable, that variable will be created and is either zero or empty string, depending on context. Before encounter *yahoo*, variable y is 0, so the script does not print anything. After encounter *yahoo*, y is 1, so every line after that will be printed.

## Sed

Or, using *sed*, the following will delete everything up to and including the line with yahoo:

```
sed '1,/yahoo/d' data.txt
```

Comment: could you please explain the awk syntax a bit? 
My understanding:
/yahoo/ search for the line using regular expression, then from that line on, create a variable called y and then set its value to 1, then if the line should be printed depends on the value of y. Then every line would be printed after yahoo. I am not quite sure of the "next" command

Comment: My bad, I forgot to explain. Please see my update.

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly it should read like this:

y=0

for line in file:

    if (/yahoo/):

        y=1

        go to next line

    if (y!=1):

        print line

Comment: If you want to include the part `http://www.yahoo.com` as well, you can use `awk '/yahoo/{y=1}y' data.txt`

Comment: @KoheiNozaki Or simply: `awk '/yahoo/,0' data.txt`. And if you know that the search string is towards the end of the file, printing the remainder using `sed` would be done using `sed -n -e '/yahoo/,$p' data.txt`

Comment: very good explanation, thanks

Answer (score 14):

This is much easier done with `sed` than `grep`.  `sed` can apply any of its one-letter commands to an inclusive range of lines; the general syntax for this is

```
START , STOP COMMAND
```

except without any spaces.  `START` and `STOP` can each be a number (meaning "line number N", starting from 1); a dollar sign (meaning "the end of the file"), or a regexp enclosed in slashes, meaning "the first line that matches this regexp".  (The exact rules are slightly more complicated; [the GNU `sed` manual has more detail](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses).)

So, you can do what you want like so:

```
sed -n -e '/http:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com/,$p' file1 > file2
```

The `-n` means "don't print anything unless specifically told to", and the `-e` directive means "from the first appearance of a line that matches the regexp `/http:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com/` to the end of the file, `p`rint."

This will include the line with `http://www.yahoo.com/` on it in the output.  If you want everything after that point but not that line itself, the easiest way to do that is to invert the operation:

```
sed -e '1,/http:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com/d' file1 > file2
```

which means "for line 1 through the first line matching the regexp `/http:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com/`, `d`elete the line" (and then, implicitly, print everything else; note that `-n` is *not* used this time).

Comment: What is $p?  Okay, it's the STOP.  When does it stop?  A google search reveals nothing.  The sed tutorials I've looked at do not mention it.

Comment: @7stud In the terms I used, the STOP is just the dollar sign; the 'p' is the COMMAND. '`/.../,$`' means "do something starting with the first line matching the regular expression and continuing until the end of the file", and 'p' means 'print'.  http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html might be helpful.

Comment: *the 'p' is the COMMAND* -- Ahh.  Why not write it as : `/../,$ p?` for clarity, with the format being `START,STOP COMMAND`?

Comment: @7stud It won't work if you do that.  Well, I suppose modern implementations might have relaxed the syntax, but in the *traditional* Unix Version 7 implementation, no whitespace allowed between the address and the command.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk '/yahoo/ ? c++ : c' file1
```

Or golfed

```
awk '/yahoo/?c++:c' file1
```

Result

```
http://www.baidu.com
http://www.yandex.com
```

Answer (score 3):

This is most easily done in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print unless 1 .. m(http://www\.yahoo\.com)' file
```

In other words, print all lines that ***aren’t*** between line 1 and the first  occurrence of that pattern.

Comment: it works, too. Never use Perl before at all. what does the 1 .. m(search) mean, the syntax looks different from other programming languages. Not quite straight forward..

Comment: @user84771 It means from when the current line number is through a line that matches that search. Normally the search is with `/search/` but I didn’t want to have to escape the slashes. For example, you could say `print if 1 .. /^$/` to print up through and including a blank line.

Comment: For those who still find this one-liner cryptic, the key is the range operator (the double-dot). In scalar context, the range operator acts as a flip-flop that maintains its own boolean state. Also, when one of its operands is a constant (like "1" above), it matches against the current line number of the input being evaluated. Details here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Answer (score 2):

Using this script:

```
# Get index of the "yahoo" word
index=`grep -n "yahoo" filepath | cut -d':' -f1`

# Get the total number of lines in the file
totallines=`wc -l filepath | cut -d' ' -f1`

# Subtract totallines with index
result=`expr $total - $index`

# Gives the desired output
grep -A $result "yahoo" filepath
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing what is a basic `sed` one-liner?

Comment: was just trying to reply grep question with grep answer.

Comment: that is very helpful user1502952..  thanks a lot! but seems like next time I have an ad-hoc query, I would go with sed or awk :)

Comment: Probably a pure GNU grep answer would be `grep -Pzo '.*yahoo(.*\n)*' data.txt` or in the spirit of the script, however in one line: `grep -A$(wc -l < data.txt) yahoo data.txt`.