# Is there a adb shell command to know all activitynames of a package

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 0 experience in Android, so this basic question.

I am not a programmer, so i want something like shell commands than code.

In my phone i have set of applications installed. I can know how to find list of packages of the application by

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

From the list of packages that displayed with above command, Once i know my package name(say xyz package) what shell command i have to use to list all the activities under that package(xyz package).

Is there a way to know activity names from the apk file? I can get the apk file name from the package my using

```
 adb shell pm list packages -f "my package name"
```

So can you please let me know the shell command to list of activity names from the apk file.

Answer (score 3):

> So can you please let me know the shell command to list of activity names from the apk file.

Assuming you have access to the APK file, you can use `aapt` (which comes with the Android SDK build tools) to read the contents of the packaged manifest:

```
aapt l -a filename.apk
```

The output also includes a (potentially large) list of all resources and identifiers. The manifest-specific output should be at the bottom.

If you're only interested in the manifest and don't care about the resources and stuff, you could leverage `sed` to skip all other content:

```
aapt l -a filename.apk | sed -n -e '/manifest/,$p'
```

Sample output:

```
Android manifest:
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=2)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x2
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.1" (Raw: "1.1")
    A: package="com.example.packagename" (Raw: "com.example.packagename")
    E: uses-sdk (line=4)
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x7
      A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0xf
    E: uses-permission (line=6)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
    E: uses-permission (line=7)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
    E: uses-permission (line=8)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
    E: uses-permission (line=9)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.CAMERA" (Raw: "android.permission.CAMERA")
    E: uses-feature (line=11)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.hardware.camera" (Raw: "android.hardware.camera")
    E: application (line=13)
      A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x1030007
      A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0a001e
      A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f020077
      A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Application" (Raw: ".Application")
      E: activity (line=14)
        A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0a001e
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity1" (Raw: ".Activity1")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
        E: intent-filter (line=15)
          E: action (line=16)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
          E: category (line=18)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
      E: activity (line=21)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity2" (Raw: ".Activity2")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
        A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x2
      E: activity (line=22)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity3" (Raw: ".Activity3")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
      E: activity (line=23)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity4" (Raw: ".Activity4")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
      E: activity (line=24)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity5" (Raw: ".Activity5")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
        A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x2
      E: activity (line=25)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity6" (Raw: ".Activity6")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x1
      E: activity (line=26)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)=".Activity7" (Raw: ".Activity7")
        A: android:screenOrientation(0x0101001e)=(type 0x10)0x0
```

You can probably filter further to get to just the activity names, but I'll leave that up yourself to figure out. :)

References:

- [Android aapt](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt)
- [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)
- [How to get the part of file after the line that matches grep expression ? (first match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103531/how-to-get-the-part-of-file-after-the-line-that-matches-grep-expression-first)

Answer (score 2):

`adb shell dumpsys package <packageName>`  will list all activity of a package with all activity names and corresponding intents

Answer (score 1):

you get it like this:

```
adb shell "dumpsys package | grep -i 'com.android.calendar' | grep 'Activity'"
```

It will gives like below:

```
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity
        9a9edbd com.android.calendar/.event.EventInfoActivity
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity
        9a9edbd com.android.calendar/.event.EventInfoActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        a148bb4 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.travel.EmptyTravelActivity
        e8883dd com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.web.WebViewActivity
        26664e6 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.loan.LoanDetailActivity
        2c883c5 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.holiday.HolidayDetailActivity
        304220e com.android.calendar/.agenda.AgendaActivity
        31751c3 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.test.ModuleTestActivity
        408a44b com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.travel.FlightDetailActivity
        5e67a3c com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.detail.CardDetailActivity
        6befe28 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.travel.TrainDetailActivity
        6e4511a com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.insertevent.InsertEventActivity
        83b3a27 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.movie.MovieDetailActivity
        879f009 com.android.calendar/.selectcalendars.SelectVisibleCalendarsActivity
        ba96a40 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.travel.FlightCheckInActivity
        bb29741 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.credit.CreditDetailActivity
        ca3e972 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.electricity.ElectricityBillDetailActivity
        e19d4d4 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.hotel.HotelDetailActivity
        fd0667d com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.event.gas.GasBillDetailActivity
        ff6f42f com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.huangli.HuangLiDetailActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        134bba0 com.android.calendar/.settings.CalendarSettingsActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        9a9edbd com.android.calendar/.event.EventInfoActivity
        de026b2 com.android.calendar/com.miui.calendar.detail.GlobalHoroscopeDetailActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        304220e com.android.calendar/.agenda.AgendaActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity (2 filters)
        9a9edbd com.android.calendar/.event.EventInfoActivity
        e7285bc com.android.calendar/.homepage.AllInOneActivity
        5697056 com.android.calendar/.event.EditEventActivity (2 filters)
```