# Delete the lines from file between pattern match

Tags: shell, sed

How to delete all the lines between two pattern in file using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed).

Here pattern are `//test` and `//endtest`, file content:

```
blah blah blah
c
f
f
[
]
//test
all text to be deleted 
line1
line2
xyz
amv
{
//endtest
l
dsf
dsfs
```

Expected result:

```
blah blah blah
c
f
f
[
]
//test
//endtest
l
dsf
dsfs
```

Comment: see also [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/)

Comment: If `awk` is a viable alternative for you you should checkout this answer I wrote some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112076/42580

Comment: Don't use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate code when your requirements change in the slightest (e.g. to test some value inside the range or include/exclude the range start/end lines). Use a flag variable instead. Since sed doesn't have variables that means you shouldn't use sed for tasks like this, just use awk instead, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721516/1745001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is common feature of `sed`

```
 sed '/^\/\/test$/,/^\/\/endtest/d'
```

As `/` is used to bound regex, they have to be escaped, in regex.

If you want to keep marks (as requested):

```
sed '/^\/\/test$/,/^\/\/endtest/{//!d}'
```

Explanation:

Have a look at `info sed`, search for *`sed address`* -> *`Regexp Addresses`* and *`Range Addresses`*.

Enclosed by `{ ... }`, symbol `//` mean any bound.

> The empty regular expression '//' repeats the last regular
>        expression match (the same holds if the empty regular expression is
>        passed to the 's' command).

`!` mean *`not`*, then `d` for *`delete line`*

Alternative: You could write:

```
sed '/^\/\/\(end\)\?test$/,//{//!d}'
```

or

```
sed -E '/^\/\/(end)?test$/,//{//!d}'
```

Will work same, but care, this could reverse effect if some extra pattern `//endtest` may exist ***before*** first open pattern (`//test`).

... All this was done, using **GNU `sed`  4.4**!

### Under MacOS, *BSD `sed`*

Under MacOS, I've successfully dropped wanted lines with this syntax:

```
sed '/^\/\/test$/,/^\/\/endtest/{/^\/\/\(end\)\{0,1\}test$/!d;}'
```

or

```
sed -E '/^\/\/test$/,/^\/\/endtest/{/^\/\/(end)?test$/!d;}'
```

Comment: getting below error https://stackoverflow.com/users/1765658/f-hauri            `sed '/^\/\/test$/,/^\/\/endtest/{//!d}' test.txt
sed: bad regex '': empty (sub)expression`

Comment: wich version of `sed` (and OS) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
$ awk '/\/\/endtest/{p=0} !p; /\/\/test/{p = 1}' file
blah blah blah
c
f
f
[
]
//test
//endtest
l
dsf
dsfs
```

Comment: You should delete your answer as it was clearly written that the solution should be solved with sed. Or?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName no, the question was edited after I answered

Comment: Then you will recieve 1UP from me :-D

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName people often post questions asking for an answer in some specific tool just because they don't know any better. Restricting answers to just the tool they asked for (unless they're very specific that they can ONLY use that tool) while there's a better solution using some other tool isn't useful. In this case sed and awk are both standard tools that exist in every UNIX installation and people often get confused about which of them to use for which task so it's very common for people to ask for a solution in 1 and accept a solution in the other.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E '/\/\/test/,/\/\/endtest/{/\/\/.*test/!d}' d
```