# How to obtain the first line after matched string regardless of string presence

Tags: bash

Say I have this as input:

```
..pattern1...this
..pattern1...1
..pattern1...2
...
```

Or

```
..pattern1...0
..pattern2...0
..pattern1...1
..pattern2...1
..pattern2...2
..pattern1...this
...
```

I.e. list of lines containing only two types of patterns (strings).
I'm trying to obtain the *first* line of `pattern1` after the *last* line of `pattern2`. If there is no `pattern2` then the first line of `pattern1`. 
Example output for both cases would be:

```
 ..pattern1...this
```

I can do either one of this cases separately with `sed` ([like with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103531/how-to-get-the-part-of-file-after-the-line-that-matches-grep-expression-first)) but I wasn't able to get a command which would do both ad the same time.

Anyone can jump in and lend an hand? Thanks!

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` on it's own as it's highly ambiguous - when you say `pattern` do you mean `string` or `regexp` or something else? Do you want full-line matches or full-word matches or partial matches on either or something else? What should the output be given your posted sample input? Please [edit] your question to address all of that.

Comment: Thanks. tried to clear it up. In my particular case i'm fine with strings

Comment: `fine with` or `require`? If you're `fine with strings` then that implies you're `fine with regexps` too and the code would be briefer for regexp than string matching.

Comment: Well, indeed as you say, a solution with regex it's absolutely fine. In my particular case i'm lucky enough to have to match something easy like abc_123 which works fine with both regex or strings. Thanks.

Comment: and if `abc_1234` exists in your input then it's also considered as matching `abc_123`, right?

Comment: What if there is no `pattern1` after the last occurrence of `pattern2`?

Comment: @anishsane: empty answer is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/pattern1/ && !line{line=$0} /pattern2/{line=""} END{print line}' file
```

1. When `pattern1` is found, set the `line` variable to entire line.
2. When we find pattern1 again, ignore it. (since `line` will already be set.)
3. When `pattern2` is found, reset `line` variable, so that the next occurance of `pattern1` is respected.

And Ed Morton's answer has already mentioned how to handle, if you want exact line match or if you want to take pattern from a shell variable. Adding my answer only to suggest that use of `tac` can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Given one interpretation of your question this might be what you need:

If `pattern` means `regexp` and you're OK with partial rather than full matches then:

```
tac file | awk '/pattern1/{line=$0; f=1} /pattern2/{exit} END{if (f) print line}'
```

If you need full regexp matches then add start/end anchors (`/^pattern1$/`) and compare to a specific field (e.g. `$4 ~ /^pattern1$/`) instead of the whole line if you need word instead of line matches.

If you need string matches instead of regexp then use `index()` or `==` against `$0` or `$N` (where N is your target field number) as appropriate.

If pattern1 and pattern2 are shell variables and given a whole bunch of assumptions about what a "pattern" might be:

```
tac file | awk -v re1="$pattern1" -v re2="$pattern2" '$0 ~ re1{line=$0; f=1} $0 ~ re2{exit} END{if (f) print line}'
```

Comment: Works for example n.2 but doesn't work with example n.1 where there is no pattern2

Comment: now works, thanks! why the final tac? should be only 1 line so there should be no need?

Comment: Force of habit. Your problem is just a reduced version of the common problem of finding the last N occurrences of something solved idiomatically by `tac | cmd | tac`. I'll remove that final `tac`.

Comment: Thank you! by the way, how can i modify the pattern1 and pattern2 in case they are bash variables like $pattern1, $pattern2 ? Thanks!

Comment: I added an example of that to the end of my answer.