# awk - ignore pattern

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I'm trying to extract some text using awk.

Here is the sample file:

```
...
var a=2;
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
other text
//this is a comment with brackets []
```

So, when I execute the following command :

```
awk '/var/ , /;/' file
```

I obtain :

```
var a=2;
var x=[
        0, 1;
```

Result expected :

```
var a=2;
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
```

Logically, the previous command took the first `;` and print the result.

The process should ignore `;` if that one is matching with the following regex: `^[\t\ ]{1,}[0-9,]{1,}.*;$`

Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: How about `awk '/var/ , /];/' file` ?

Comment: A generalization and enhancement of the concept could be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112076/42580

Comment: @wolfgunner : side note : for `ERE`, you can trim :::::::: ::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::  `(\[|\(|\{).*[;].*(\]|\)|\{)` to simply `[[({].*;.*[]){]`  :::::::::::::::::::: ::::::: p.s. you actually want `{` on right hand side match instead of `}` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can just match `];` or `] *;` like this:

```bash
awk '/var/ , /] *;/' file

var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
```

Comment: We could have another line (i.e comment) like : `//this is an array []`, so the output prints also the latest line !!

Comment: We are matching `]` followed by 0 or more whitespaces then a `;` but your comment line doesn't have `;`

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and show updated input with expected output so that may be I can understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested with shown samples Only.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)var x=\\[[^]]*\\]' 'RT && sub(/^\n/,"",RT){print RT}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    RS="^$"                                         # read in the whole file
}
{
    while(match($0,/var([^]]|\]+[^];])*\]*\];/)) {  # look for var...];
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)             # output match
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                # continue
    }
}' file
```

A bit extended `file`:

```
some text
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
other text
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
more text
```

Output:

```
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mawk '/=[[]/,/[]];$/'
> ```

```
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
```

or shrink it down to this but it's less clear :

> ```
> gawk '/=\[/,/];$/'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- no nested `]`
- each `var` is guaranteed to have a pair of matching `[` and `]`

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk '/var/,/]/' file
var x=[
        0, 1;
        1,0;
        2,1;
        3,2];
```